# Adding a new property to Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've actually had quite a bit of trouble finding an answer to this question.

If I create a new document in a collection, I can give it whatever properties I want.

Is there a way to add a new property to all my documents? Cosmos DB seems to be resisting everything I've tried. Do I have to delete the existing documents and make new ones?

It would be nice to know how to do this in C# code, if possible. Javascript is fine too, though.

Answer (score 1):

CosmosDB does not support partial document updates so you would have to Update all of your existing documents with the new property if you really need it there. There are many ways you can do that including stored procedures.

If you are ok to use C# then you can do that easily with [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut)

```
var items = await cosmoStore.Query().ToListAsync();
foreach(var item in items){
   item.YourProperty = "YourValue";
}
await cosmosStore.UpdateRangeAsync(items);
```

When selecting the items your value will default to the default property value if it's not present and by updating it, it will be added.

Comment: That's a neat tool, but I wasn't sure how to instantiate the CosmosStore object because I wasn't sure what you needed for the IDatabaseCreator and ICollectionCreator objects. You might want to add something to your documentation about that.

Comment: You can use the ServiceCollection() to create a ServiceProvider and use `AddCosmosStore`. If you don't use that then just create a `DocumentClient` from the `DocumentClientFactory` and initialize using `new CosmosStore<TEntity>(settings, new CosmosDatabaseCreator(documentClient), new CosmosCollectionCreator(documentClient))`. I will add that in the README file thank you very much for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks for that. Beyond that, it seems though that my documents can't be updated through ANY means. I can edit a certain document I created recently in the data explorer, but not others. Are there per-document permissions at play? Or is something else locking them down?

Comment: That is very bizarre. So to get this straight, you can edit some documents manually but not some others? What's different about them?

Comment: Yes, and I'm not sure. There doesn't seem to be any method to the madness. In one document adding certain key value pairs works, but adding others doesn't.

Comment: Does you collection have a partition key? Partition keys cannot be updated.

Comment: No, I think I found the issue: these documents are constantly updated from outside sources. I feel like a dummy!

Answer (score 0):

Using https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/python/api/azure-cosmos/azure.cosmos.cosmos_client.cosmosclient?view=azure-python#upsertitem-database-or-container-link--document--options-none- was pretty straightforward.

```
import azure.cosmos.cosmos_client as cosmos_client
import azure.cosmos.errors as errors
import azure.cosmos.http_constants as http_constants

import os
import json

url = 'https://yourdb.documents.azure.com:443/'
key = 'key'
client = cosmos_client.CosmosClient(url, {'masterKey': key})

database_id = 'database_id '
container_id =  'container_id '


for item in client.QueryItems("dbs/" + database_id + "/colls/" + container_id,
                              'SELECT * FROM ' + container_id + ' ',
                              {'enableCrossPartitionQuery': True}):

    item["field"] = "value"
    newItem = client.UpsertItem("dbs/" + database_id + "/colls/" + container_id, item)
    print(json.dumps(newItem, indent=True))
```