# Cosmos DB alter collection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am pretty new to Azure so this question might sound a little silly to some, apologies for that! Actually, I have a requirement where I need to alter the structure of an existing cosmos db collection to fit in one additional property. How can I do that with a Stored Procedure? Now,my scenario is somewhat like I have an existing collection which has approximately around 60 documents and the same collection is present in other environments also. I need to add a single property to the collection structure which should ideally be an one time activity.

I have checked [Adding a new property to Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280374/adding-a-new-property-to-cosmos-db) but unlike this, my requirement is not to update the collection through code(C#), instead it is through a SP like I said. Now, since we can't use anything apart from SELECT query with Cosmos DB, how do I fit in an ALTER document functionality in the below code snippet?

```
function updateDocument(documentName){
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();
    collection.queryDocuments(

     // ALTER document code goes here

    );
}
```

Comment: why not from c#?

Comment: Because it(updating an existing collection structure) is a one time change that I need to do

Comment: @Deblina - Please see the answers posted: you cannot perform updates via Cosmos DB SQL.

Comment: yes @David I get it..I have updated my question to make my requirement more clear..please have a look

Comment: Using c# is not a limiting factor, it depends on what you are use to coding with. You can knock up batch updates in a few minutes and then use things like the 'ActionBlock' to multithread it all up so you can update huge numbers in very little time (I up the RU before any large update). BUT, I think I should also learn to do this stuff in function :)

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB is a schema-less NoSQL database. Each document is completely independent from each other and it doesn't require you to change anything in order to add a new property. You can go straight to the portal and do it or programmatically though an SDK or a stored procedure.

SQL queries in Cosmos DB cannot alter the documents in a collection. It can only be used for querying.

Stored procedures can change a document but it requires you to read the document first and then update it. Keep in mind that they can be executed against a single logical partition.

I would highly suggest you read more about CosmosDB because it sounds like you don't fully understand what it is.

You can start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started

Comment: with stored procedures how can I update a document? I have I have updated my question to make my requirement more clear..please have a look

Comment: @Deblina There are multiple examples that explain exactly how you can do that. The CosmsoDB stored proc repo is full of them.

Answer (score 0):

First off: There is no enforced schema, either at the document level or at the collection level. Store whatever document properties you want.

As for updating documents: the Core (SQL) API only provides *querying* via SQL (e.g. `SELECT` statements). For creates, updates, or deletes, you must use API / SDK calls.

Comment: But @David, what if I don't want to use API / SDK calls? My scenario is like I have an existing collection which has approximately around 60 documents and the same collection is present in other environments also. I need to add a single property to the collection structure which should ideally be an one time activity, right?